# Hive external table with parquet data not selecting data

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, parquet

I have Hive external table with parquet data. There is no compression being utilized here. I am writing data (parquet files) to the HDFS directory using a spark job. But when I try to select data from table, I get below error/warning and output doesn't appear. 
I am sure that this is a common problem. Please let me know how can I overcome this?

Hive - 1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245
hdp - 2.5.0.0-1245
spark version 1.6.2

> Jun 1, 2017 5:04:27 PM WARNING: org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics: Ignoring statistics because created_by could not be parsed (see PARQUET-251): parquet-mr version 1.6.0
>   org.apache.parquet.VersionParser$VersionParseException: Could not parse created_by: parquet-mr version 1.6.0 using format: (.+) version ((.*) )?(build ?(.*))
>    at org.apache.parquet.VersionParser.parse(VersionParser.java:112)
>           at org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics.shouldIgnoreStatistics(CorruptStatistics.java:60)
>           at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:263)

It seems that because the parquet writer version used in spark job and the one used to read in Hive is different and there is a gap between them. Here we can see in Hive the version being used to read is parquet-mr version 1.6.0

Now, If anybody can tell me how can I change the version of parquet writer used in spark job OR how to change Hive parquet reader version, I can try that to resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

The exception you see is harmless.